# Failed to set defaults using PnP js method SetDefaultColumnValues for a SharePoint library using SPFX webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnpjs

I am developing a SPFX webpart which creates a SharePoint library, Add content type to the library, Delete Default Document content type and set default column values for the Managed Metadata columns added through content type.

While setting default column values for the fields using PnP method SetDefaultColumnValues shown below, it throws error "Field does not exist,please check internal name.Failed to set defaults", eventhough the fields exist already. When I apply breakpoint in the setdefaultvalue function and debug, the default values set successfully. When I run without breakpoints, it is throwing below error.

[image]
Below is the PnP function which causes the error
[image]

I have used Async/Await in all the functions as all the functionalities needs to be executed sequentially.

Please provide your valuable suggestions and insights on how to make the solution work! Also please mention if any other possible ways to set the default values for the MMD fields using SPFX.

Edited
I have added settimeout for 10 secs before calling the SetDefaultColumnValues function.It is working fine after this change.But I doubt whether this will work all the time or based on certain conditions there are chances to fail.

Comment: Confirm once if you are using correct **internal names** of your columns. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Thank you for your response. yes the internal names are right. The same code works fine if I debug into the function mentioned above. I doubt if I need to add some functionality like settimeout or something.to wait for columns to be available which is added through content types from previous function. I have used Async and await in my functions.

Comment: It sounds like an order of execution error or your code is reaching the SetDefaultColumnValues before SharePoint has had chance to fully add the content type to the library. You might need some sort of delay or a retry/check for the columns in the library.